# MySQL You can't specify target table 'meterValue' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE meterValue 
SET `value` = (SELECT `value` FROM meterValue WHERE id = 160435)+1 WHERE id = 160435;
```

It's not running...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UPDATE meterValue SET value = value+1 WHERE id = 160435
```